# How can i find equation that does not have a solution?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

An operation $*$ is defined on the set $\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}$, ie. the set containing all pairs of integers by:

$$
(u,v) * (x,y)=(u+x,v \cdot y)
$$

if $(\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}, *)$ is not a group what is an equation that does not have a solution?

i have found the the identity element (0,1) and the inverse element (-u,1/v) but how can i find an equation that does not have a solution?

Comment: You have a typo - the second occurrence of "identity element" should "inverse element".

Comment: HINT: $\frac1v$ is not necessarily an integer, so your supposed inverse element need not even by in the set.

Comment: i edited my question but still am not getting your hint, can you clarify your solution

Answer (score 0):

Hint: your inverse element doesn't always exist. When would $(-u, \frac{1}{v})$ fail to exist for $u, v \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: i am not getting your hint, can you clarify your solution

Comment: Clarified by writing more words, rather than adding any new thought into it.

Comment: if v is not 1 or -1 right?

Comment: @jason That will do, yes. Specifically, if $v = 0$ then $\frac{1}{v}$ isn't even in $\mathbb{R}$, let alone $\mathbb{Z}$.